# Why is this regular expression accepting special characters and numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've created a simple regular expression for email. It is:
`/[a-z]+@{1}[a-z]{2,}/`
Now the problem is that it's accepting an email like `something;;99@asd` when tested. But it shouldn't allow `;;99` ?
I want letters only.

Secondly, please tell me about beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) symbols used in regular expression. I read about them on codeacademy but couldn't understand their purpose. Do they have something to do with my original problem?

**EDIT:**
Here's the whole jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $pat1=/[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}/;
        var $pat2=/[a-z]+@{1}[a-z]{2,}/;
        $(".savebutton").click(function(){
            var $name=$("input[name='pname']").val();
            var $email=$("input[name='pmail']").val();
            var $pswd=$("input[name='pswd']").val();
            if(($name!="" && $email!="") && $pswd!=""){
                if($pat1.test($name)&&$pat2.test($email)){
                    //ACTIONS               
                           }
                    }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: The regex does not match the string you supplied. See https://regex101.com/r/yS6vX1/1. Are you sure you provided the same input you used in your code?

Comment: you can drop the quantifier `{1}` as 1 is the default.

Comment: As mentioned that regex doesn't match the email you provided. Please show how your consuming the regex

Comment: @Liam check the EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex

```
/^[a-z]+@{1}[a-z]{2,}$/g
```

Your string must start with a-z (^) and end in a-z($)

^ and $ are for beginning and end

Comment: Thank you. Please read the EDIT in my question.

Comment: Will it solve my problem?

Comment: Yes it would just insert ^ and $

Comment: Well it does. Can you tell why did it allow numbers and special chars when ^ and $ weren't used?

Comment: I'm wondering how this could match a valid mail address, e.g. [`nobody@example.com`](https://regex101.com/r/kY1fX7/1)

Comment: because it would match any contiguous string then for eg 999asas@asas , then it would match asas@asas

Comment: you need add .com or some other domain (regex) to be  complete email regex

Comment: I'm just learning. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @SebastianProske keep wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Your Regular Expression looks fine. I tested it on few test cases.

1. ***Symbol ^*** Matches the **beginning** of the string, or the beginning of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled. *This matches a position, not a character.*
2. ***Symbol $*** Matches the **end** of the string, or the end of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled. *This matches a position, not a character.*

For example, if you have to match pattern of exactly length 3, Then you can use **^** and **$** to denote beginning and end of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

An example of email regex is like this

```
 /^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/m
```

for your question,

> **Please tell me about beginning (^) and end ($) symbols used in regular expression...**

In my example regex above, both symbols are best used if your using the multiline (**m**) modifier in you regex. (**^**) is used to identify the beginning of the line and (**$**) is used to identify the end of the line. It does affect your original problem but I would suggest you use this symbols in your regular expression.

Hope me help well.